# Session clear and page refresh

Tags: asp-classic

Using classic ASP I want to clear a form that auto populates with session variables upon loading.

I need to clear all of the session variables using a button.

I was using js to clear the text boxes but the session still exists.

I then tried a html reset button, but that didn't clear the session either.

So know I am trying to find a way to clear the ASP session variables using classic ASP.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I created a page with session.abandon and had the submit button call it and redirect back to the current page. Works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A form `reset()` clears the form data on the client. This has nothing to do with the server session.

`<% Session.Abandon %>` clears the session on the server.

Answer (score 16):

different ways depending on what you want to accomplish:

`session("var") = ""` will blank the value.

`Session.Contents.Remove("var")` will remove the variable

`Session.Contents.RemoveAll()` will remove all variables

or if you just want to start a new ASP session altogether you can do `session.abandon`