# asp cancel button clear session variables

Tags: asp-classic

I found this:
"I created a page with session.abandon and had the submit button call it and redirect back to the current page. Works."
on this URL:
[Session clear and page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299473/session-clear-and-page-refresh)

Using classic ASP I have an .asp page/form used for alternate log-in using email address and answer to 'secret question'. If person enters email address and clicks 'SUBMIT', I retrieve the 'secret question' from the database. I store BOTH the address and question in session variables.

In Step 2 the person is prompted to enter 'answer' to the question and SUBMIT again. All of this works fine. Log-in achieved... life is good!

If, for whatever reason, the person decides to stop without entering the answer (in effect, abandons the log-in), the session variables remain.

I have struggled to find a method (within my limited coding capability) to clear these specific session variables. I know the syntax to clear individual (or all) session variables. I just cannot figure out how to 'trigger' (that is, 'execute') Session.RemoveAll. The quote and URL at the top indicate someone knows how to do this... but he did not say HOW he did it so that I can duplicate that process.

Can anyone lead me by the hand on this one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables will clear themselves at whatever time the server is set to consider the session abandoned (typically 10 - 20 minutes). You've got two options:

- You can shorten the session timeout on the server, but it will cause problems if your site has natural places of long inactivity.
- You could use `Session.Timeout` to adjust the timeout for that one page.

If they've truly abandoned the session - they're not performing any actions - then there's nothing to attach a trigger to. The bit at the top of your question is running `Session.Abandon` on submit - not the same scenario you are describing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about 'normal' session timeout. Did not know I could set timeout for the page. I may go that route. I was hoping there was a method to 'run' Session("xxx") = "" using a button click. Thanks again for the information.

Comment: Session.Timeout seems to be the easiest route. I think I will try using a GIF ("Cancel.gif") as part of a hyperlink to an asp page. That page would consist only of the several lines that set session variables to Null and a redirect back to the hyperlink page. That's fairly easy to do... I'll see if it works and eliminates the timeout period.  Thanks again, @anonJr